# What is the .p file in C?

Tags: c, sdl

I have found [this project](https://github.com/Cadynum/snake) on Github, a simple snake game with SDL. Inside this project the person seems to be forward declaring a bunch of functions inside a [file](https://github.com/Cadynum/snake/blob/master/snake.p) with the .p extension.

What is this extension? I have never come across this before. They call this file just before the [main function](https://github.com/Cadynum/snake/blob/master/snake.c#L254), why does C read this as a valid format and seemingly have no issue with it? Is the .p extension an actual part of the language that I have not encountered? If not, is it possible to put any extension on the end of a file and have it compile as long as it is valid C?

Comment: The last statement is true. The compiler doesn't really care about the extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `snake.p` included in that project is a C header file.

C compilers typically care about the name of the source files that they're given on the command line. For example, a C source file might be called `foo.c`, so

```
gcc -c foo.c
```

will cause gcc to assume that it contains C source code. Other suffixes indicate other languages (`.cpp` for C, `.adb` for Ada, etc.).  (There's also an option to specify the language explicitly, but it's so rarely used that I don't even remember what it is, and it's very likely to vary for different compilers.)

Header files (also known as include files), however, are not normally passed as arguments on the compiler's command line, so the same requirements don't apply. There's a nearly universal convention of using a `.h` extension for C header files, but when the preprocessor sees a `#include` directive, all it really cares about is the contents of the file, not the form of its name.

I've seen a `.inc` extension used for unusual include files (that contain function definitions rather than the usual declarations seen in most header files).

In this particular project, the file `snake.p` is generated from the `snake.c` file using a tool called `cproto`. The relevant command in the `Makefile` is:

```
.c.p:
        @$(CPROTO) $(CPROTOFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@ &>/dev/null
```

which says that `snake.p` can be generated from `snake.c` by running the `cproto` command, which generates C prototypes (function declarations) from C source code containing function definitions. Probably the `.p` stands for "prototypes".

It would be more usual to name the `snake.p` file `snake.h`, since it's just a header file. It would also be more usual *not* to include that file in the distribution, since it's generated automatically by the build process -- but perhaps the author wanted users who haven't installed `cproto` to be able to build the project.

Bottom line: It's just an unusual choice by the author of the project. I can't think of any good reason to use a `.p` extension rather than the conventional `.h` extension, but it doesn't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of the `.p` extension, but it looks like a header file. You're right in saying that C compilers don't care what extensions you give it.

Comment: Wow, is that a common feature of most languages? I thought the file format mattered, I guess it's just for the programmers benefit? Would I be correct in assuming this means that you could (not should) program a C application using only header files? Or is there some distinction between .h and .c? (I know you basically answered this already, just looking for 100% clarity) Cheers

Comment: There are several/many default rules in make.  Such rules expect the source files to end in .c and header files to end in .h

Answer (score 0):

.p usually associates with matlab applications. 
[link](http://filext.com/file-extension/P) breaks down what other languages associates with .p 
and yes that's true the compiler doesn't care for the extension of the file